# Unable to connect EntityFramework to DB2 Provider

Tags: .net, entity-framework, db2, ado.net, machine.config

I have been trying to migrate to another computer while also upgrading from VS2012 to VS2019... so far I have upgraded target framework from .Net v4.0 to v4.7.2. As well as EntityFramework is v6.4.4

Current states:

Machine config -

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
  <add name="IBM DB2 .NET Data Provider 11.1.3030" invariant="IBM.Data.DB2.11.1.3030" description="IBM DB2 Data Provider 11.1.3030 for .NET Framework 4.0" type="IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2.11.1.3030, Version=11.1.3030.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208"/>
  <add name="IBM Informix .NET Data Provider 11.1.3030" invariant="IBM.Data.Informix.11.1.3030" description="IBM Informix Data Provider 11.1.3030 for .NET Framework 4.0" type="IBM.Data.Informix.IfxFactory, IBM.Data.Informix.11.1.3030, Version=11.1.3030.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Initial error when running -

Exception: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed."
Source: EntityFramework

When printing out all provider factory classes I get these providers (which make sense when looking at machine.config)

IBM DB2 .NET Data Provider 11.1.3030
IBM DB2 Data Provider 11.1.3030 for .NET Framework 4.0
IBM.Data.DB2.11.1.3030
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2.11.1.3030, Version=11.1.3030.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208

IBM Informix .NET Data Provider 11.1.3030
IBM Informix Data Provider 11.1.3030 for .NET Framework 4.0
IBM.Data.Informix.11.1.3030
IBM.Data.Informix.IfxFactory, IBM.Data.Informix.11.1.3030, Version=11.1.3030.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208

From there I tried changing an existing line in Web.config from...

```
  <provider invariantName="IBM.Data.DB2" type="IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework.DB2ProviderServices, IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework, Version=10.5.5.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..." />
```

to

```
  <provider invariantName="IBM.Data.DB2.11.1.3030" type="IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework.DB2ProviderServices, IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework, Version=11.1.3030.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..." />
```

Exception: "Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework, Version=11.1.3030.4, ... The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference."

So I guess, EntityFramework is looking for an invariantName = "IBM.Data.DB2" but I only have "IBM.Data.DB2.11.1.3030" installed on my machine. Is there a way to redirect the entityframework to look for the other version of db2? or what would be a good way to navigate this? Let me know if I can add more information, thank you.

Comment: What package are you using for the DB2 EF Provider?  IBM provides one named EntityFramework.IBM.DB2 which should get you on the right track. That shows as a version 6.4.1. I'm not familiar with an IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework namespace whether it's from this package or another. I suspect the 11.1.3030 refrects the DB2 library version more than the Provider EF actually talks to.

Comment: hi Steve, looks like I do use that package:
<package id="EntityFramework.IBM.DB2" version="6.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />

Comment: I've been replacing anywhere providerName/invariantName="IBM.Data.DB2" with ="IBM.Data.DB2.11.1.3030" and now getting an A/B DB casting error where the incorrect one originates in the gac util... so might try finding a way to update that when i get time